# In Microsoft-Excel 2007 How do if find a subset of numbers that add to a given total?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

How do I find a subset of numbers that add to a given total?  For example:  i have a column of numbers indicating payments received.  I need to match these various numbers to a total deposit amount.

Comment: I don't think there is a builtin that would handle that, but a macro could certainly be made to work that out.

Comment: See [this SU post](http://superuser.com/questions/204925/excel-find-a-subset-of-numbers-that-add-to-a-given-total).

Answer (score 0):

There is a cheap Excel add-in that finds the combinations of numbers that give a desired sum.
You can find it here: [SumMatch.com](http://www.summatch.com/)